# django channels async process

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-asyncio, django-channels

I am still pretty new to django-channels and directly starting with channels 2.0 so diverse examples are still a bit hard to find yet. I am trying to understand how can I create an asynchronous process in a channel and make a js client listen to it?

while connecting to my consumer, I am checking for a running stream on a thread and try to send back predictions on the channel. This process is asynchronous but I am not sure how to properly use an AsyncConsumer or AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer.

so far I have a simple consumer like this:
**consumers.py**

```
import threading
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
from .views import readStream

class My_Consumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):

    groups = ["broadcast"]
    the_thread_name = 'TestThread'

    def connect(self):
        the_thread = None
        self.accept()
        # check if there is an active stream on a thread
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            if thread.name == self.the_thread_name:
                the_thread = thread
                break
        if the_thread == None:
            xsLog.infoLog('No Stream found yet...')
            self.close()
        else:
            the_stream = readStream()
            #...
            the_estimator = joblib.load('some_file','r')
            the_array = np.zeros(shape=(1,93), dtype=float)
            self.predict(the_thread,the_stream,the_array,the_estimator)


    def disconnect(self,close_code):

        pass

    async def predict(self,the_thread,the_stream,the_array,the_estimator):

        while the_thread.isAlive():
            sample = await the_stream.read()
            if sample != [0.0,0.0,0.0] and 'nan' not in str(sample):
                the_array = np.roll(self.the_array,-3)
                the_array[0][-3] = sample[0]
                the_array[0][-2] = sample[1]
                the_array[0][-1] = sample[2]
                new_val = await '{},{}'.format(the_estimator.predict(the_array)[0][0],the_estimator.predict(the_array)[0][1])

                await self.send_json(new_val)
```

my **js client** is pretty simple and tries to listen:

```
const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
webSocketBridge.connect('some_route');
        webSocketBridge.socket.addEventListener('open', function() {
            console.log("Connected to WebSocket");
        });
webSocketBridge.listen(function(message, stream) {console.log(message);});
```

**EDIT**

from the above mentionned question I tried the following simplified solution with an **AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer**:

```
import threading
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

class My_Consumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    groups = ["broadcast"]
    the_thread = None
    the_data = None
    #
    @database_sync_to_async
    def getUserData(self,the_user):
        return models.UserData.objects.filter(user=the_user,datatype='codebooks')
    #
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            if thread.name == 'some_thread_name':
                self.the_thread = thread
                break
        if self.the_thread == None:
            xsLog.infoLog('No Stream found yet...') 
            await self.close()
        else:
            the_data = await self.getUserData(the_user)
    #
    async def receive(self,content=None,text_data=None):
        await self.predict(self.the_thread,self.the_data)
    #
    async def predict(self,the_thread,the_data):
        """..."""
        while the_thread.isAlive():
            # doing something here
            new_data = data_from_thread + the_data
                self.send_json(new_data)
    #
    async def disconnect(self,close_code):
        await self.close()
```

and then I am sending once a message by the **JS client** to init the receive method    of the consumer:

```
webSocketBridge.socket.addEventListener('open', function() {
            console.log("Connected to WebSocket, Launching Predictions");
            webSocketBridge.send('');
        });
```

The issue here is that while the predict coroutine is launched it is blocking the whole receive one and my js client cannot receive any message through:

```
webSocketBridge.listen(function(message, stream) {
                    console.log(message.stream);
                 });
```

the disconnect coroutine is then also not recognized either.